# Why is this name ambiguous?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, namespaces

I lately decided to include the JavaScript V8 Engine in my project. After compiling and linking to it, I wanted to run the example from the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) guide.

It works in general, but for some reasons there are namespace conflicts when I do not specify the `v8` namespace in front of each class name. Visual Studio 2012 tells me for example, that the name `Context` would be ambiguous. But I do not understand why.

[image: example code from the Getting Started guide]

The only namespaces I include in this file are `std` and `v8`. It is a header file and before you ask, it's meant to be so since it claims to be a header-only library.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional> 
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <V8/v8.h>

namespace library_name
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace v8;

    // here comes the example code and more...
}
```

To find out where a symbol with the name `Context` might be defined too, I used the `Find Definition` command in Visual Studio, available in the context menu. This is the list of results.

[image: definitions of the name Context]

It lists for example `sf::Context` which I use in the project but not in that header. There are also definitions in cryptic namespaces located at files in a directory named `Windows Kits`. I neither know what they are for nor have I included them intentionally. I don't include other header files except from the standard library and JavaScript V8 as shown above.

Why do the `Context`s from different namespaces collides with each other? How can I fix this collisions to use the `v8` namespace?

Comment: Use the namespace name. That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: I use this line `using namespace v8;`. And I can't understand where other classes named `Context` could come from.

Comment: Use the namespace name as part of the qualified name. Using declarations, as you've seen, lead to mysterious conflicts.

Comment: What is `using namespace` for then? It makes my code more readable. But I guess this might lead into a huge discussion which isn't suitable at this place.

Comment: If you think it makes your code more readable, by all means use it. But be prepared for mysterious errors like the one that started this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try actually compiling the code. The compiler should list the actual conflicting symbols, possibly including where they are actually defined. You will need to either remove one of your usings or fully qualify the identifier.

Comment: Hey, just compiling the code solved the entire problem. It seems like it was a bug in the IntelliSense technique that claims to highlight syntax errors in Visual Studios during typing. The read underlines still show up but it compiled without warnings and errors.

Comment: Yeah, processing C++ is really complex, so in order to be fast enough to be useful, it takes some shortcuts which can lead to things getting out of sync with reality sometimes.